# group by interval showing zero

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm trying to group a query by intervals in this way:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS count, i.date
    FROM intervals i
    LEFT JOIN dtracker dt ON 
    i.date <= dt.date AND i.date + INTERVAL (NUMSEC) SECOND >= dt.date
    WHERE (SOME CONDITIONS)
    GROUP BY i.date
```

where I fill the table 'intervals' each time (cause intervals can change), and NUMSEC is changing as well depending of the intervals table.

Everything is working fine without 'WHERE', if there´s not results in some intervals, it shows 0 intervals. But if I put some conditions in 'WHERE' and there's no results, it doesn't show this interval anymore.

Seems like 'WHERE' clauses affects the whole query (it makes sense) but I need it to affect only to dtracker table. How I can do this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Accepted response number two. Only for the record: the count continues wrong unless you change `count(*)` by `count(dt.date)`. In the first case, for intervals with zero results, still shows count = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `WHERE` with another `AND` so that the conditions become part of the `LEFT JOIN ... ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll be interested by using the 'HAVING' keyword.

http://techonthenet.com/sql/having.php